# JS: indexOf() with an array of functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of functions like the following:

```
[ func1(), func2() ]
```

Now, if I `console.log(arrayOfFuncs[0])` I get `function func1()`, but what if I need to search for the index of one of these functions? For example, I need to `splice()` `func1` from this array, how can I find its index? Both `arrayOfFuncs.indexOf(func1)` and `arrayOfFuncs.indexOf('func1')` returns -1.

Comment: `arrayOfFuncs.indexOf(func1)` should work (so long as the `func1` variable points to the same function as the array value). `'func1'` is a string so obviously won't match.

Comment: How do you obtain the `func` that you are looking index for?  What is the intention of this?

Comment: Do you have an array of functions, or an array of results of function calls?

Comment: @Bergi the console.log returns an array of functions, as long as I can tell...

Comment: @WandMaker I need to splice one or more functions from this array, and I know their name

Comment: @Quentin I expected  arrayOfFuncs.indexOf(func1) to work, but it returns -1

Comment: @Mark — It might help if you provided a real [mcve]

Comment: @Mark Please provide a [mcve] with how you construct the array and how you get the function that you want to look up. Maybe they're different functions with the same name (or even closures instantiated from the same code)

Answer (score 0):

You can match using function's name property

```js
function A () {

}

function B () {

}

const functions = [B, A];

const indexOfA = functions.map(f => f.name).indexOf(A.name);

console.log(indexOfA);
```

You can also use `findIndex()`

```js
function A () {

}

function B () {

}

const functions = [B, A];

const indexOfA = functions.findIndex(f => f.name === A.name);

console.log(indexOfA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `indexOf` with function signature:

```js
const fun =() =>{console.log("1")}
const fun1 =() =>{console.log("2")}
    
console.log(arr.indexOf(fun1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to either search by function *reference* directly or by function *name* by using the [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) property:

```js
const func1 = () => {};
const func2 = () => {};

const funcs = [ func1, func2 ];

// Searching for function reference
console.log(funcs.indexOf(func1));

// Searching for function name
console.log(funcs.map((f) => f.name).indexOf('func1'));
```